# .NET winforms - SQL with TRIM() not updating binding source / table adapter

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a program which has a `TextBox` bound to a binding source, which is bound to a `TableAdapter`.  The underlying `DataTable` is generated from a SQL statement.

The statement is `select TRIM(SOMETHING) AS SOMETHING FROM TABLE`

The textbox displays the value just fine (the value is a "1").  But if you change it to say "2", the underlying data table is not updated.

If I remove the `TRIM()` from the SQL, it works just fine.  I think it has to do with the column aliasing, it's not sure how to update an column if the column is aliased (ie `AS SOMETHING`).  Can I define a mapping somewhere?

Thanks.

Comment: You're binding to a Sql expression, not a column, which won't work. Do the trim afterwards.

Comment: Or use a translator to do the trim. You should be able to add one to the BindingSource.

Comment: Try to do something like this:-

var SOMETHING = TRIM(select SOMETHING FROM TABLE)